# Proxy all subdomains of one domain to another, using Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to build a reverse proxy using Apache. 
My goal is to proxy all requests of the form `<subdomain>.domain.com/file.html` to `www.domain.com/<subdomain>/file.html`.

I somehow need to capture the `<subdomain>` of the original URL and use it to construct the target URL.

I assume that I need an Apache directive that can match regular expressions on the whole URL, instead of the part of the url after `%{HTTP_HOST}`, since my target URL contains the original URL's subdomain. For this reason I can't use the `ProxyPassMatch` directive, since it only matches the part of the URL after `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Another alternative is to use as many `VirtualHost` sections as my subdomains. But of course this solution doesn't make sense, since my subdomains will keep increasing.

Any tips on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it using Rewrite rules.

```
# Requires Apache module ``proxy_http``, ``rewrite``
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName primary.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*)    http://www.domain.com/%1%2 [P]

 </VirtualHost>
```

Basically what happens is this:

- `RewriteCond` matches all incoming requests whose URL matches *.domain.com/*
- `RewriteRule` proxies the request to the URL `http://www.domain.com/%1/%2`, where `%1`  and `%2` are the subdomain and request uri of the original request, respectively.

Comment: You got it. You got RewriteCond, and you got % (rather than $) which is a little obscure, but as far as I know necessary to this particular problem. (Aren't you missing a slash?)

Comment: @ChuckKollars: Do you mean about a slash between ``%1`` and ``%2``, in the ``RewriteRule``? The Request Uri (``%2``) already includes the slash, so it's not needed. In my explanation I included it though to make it more explicit.